# Security exception in singnalR (silverlight client)

Tags: silverlight, azure, signalr

I got an error message: "Security error." when calling following code:

```
_hubConnection.Start(new LongPollingTransport()).ContinueWith(task =>
{
  if (task.IsFaulted)
  {
    throw  new Exception(task.Exception.GetBaseException().Message);
  }
}
```

Stack trace:

at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.HttpHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0(IAsyncResult ar)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise)

Cross domain XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction,Content-Type"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Client access policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-methods="*" http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="http://*"/>
        <domain uri="https://*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Also tried to provide credentials but with the same result.

Any idea what could cause this problem?

Comment: There is a Silverlight sample under
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/samples/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Samples/silverlight.html

Try it, also use Fiddler to ensure your clientaccesspolicy.xml is found by the SL client

Comment: Thanks a lot. It turned out that I haven't specified a proper port number.

Comment: @AdamKostecki You can answer you own question. What do you mean by proper port number?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Silverlight sample under github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/samples/… Try it, also use Fiddler to ensure your clientaccesspolicy.xml is found by the SL client